# About the construction of the restriction of a Vector Bundle in John M. Lee's book

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

There are some details I want to understand in the construction of the Restriction of a Vector bundle given in John M. Lee's book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. It is given in Example 10.8:

> **Example 10.8 (Restriction of a Vector bundle).** Suppose $\pi:E\to M$ is a rank-$k$ vector bundle and $S\subseteq M$ is any subset. We
>   define the ***restriction of $E$ to $S$*** to be the set
>   $E|_S=\bigcup_{p\in S}E_p$, with the projection $E|_S\to S$ obtained
>   by restricting $\pi$. If $\Phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb{R}^k$ is
>   a local trivialization of $E$ over $U\subseteq M$, it restricts to a
>   bijective map $\Phi|_U:(\pi|_S)^{-1}(U\cup S)\to (U\cup S)\times
>  \mathbb{R}^k$, and it is easy to check that these form local
>   trivializations for a vector bundle structure on $E|_S$. If $E$ is a
>   smoooth vector bundle and $S\subseteq M$ is an immersed or embedded
>   submanifold, it follows easily from the chart lemma that $E|_S$ is a
>   smooth vector bundle. In particular, if $S\subseteq M$ is a smooth
>   (embedded or immersed) submanifold, then the restricted bundle $TM|_S$
>   is called the ***ambient tangent bundle*** over $M$.

What topologies do $S$ and $E|_S$ have? At first I thought: "it is obviously the subspace topology", but then at the end of the example, Lee mentions immersed submanifolds which may not have the subspace topology. Then I kinda ran into trouble because I don't know what topology $S$ and $E|_S$ have. We may consider $S$ and $E|_S$ with topologies such that the inclusions $S\hookrightarrow M$, $E|_S\hookrightarrow E$ and the map $\pi|_S:E|_S\to S$ are continuous, but that seems weird. This doesn't have to do with the question, but I believe $\Phi|_U$ should be $\Phi|_S$.

Also, Example 10.28 (b) says

> If $E\to M$ is a smooth vector bundle and $S\subseteq M$ is an
>   immersed submanifold with or without boundary, then the inclusion map
>   $E|_S\hookrightarrow E$ is a smooth bundle homomorphism covering the
>   inclusion of $S$ into $M$.

So now we have to prove that the inclusion map $E|_S\hookrightarrow E$ is smooth to begin with. If we only consider embedded submanifolds (which have the subspace topology), then this problem goes away because vector bundles are submersions and thus $E|_S=\pi^{-1}(S)$ is a submanifold of $E$.

There are other subtle issues when considering immersed submanifolds, e.g. Example 10.10 (b):

> Given an immersed submanifold $S\subseteq M$ with or without boundary,
>   a section of the ambient tangent bundle $TM|_S\to S$ is called a
>   vector field along $S$. It is a continuous map $X:S\to TM$ such that
>   $X_p\in T_pM$ for each $p\in S$.

If $TM|_S$ is a not a topological subspace of $TM$, then a continuous map $X:S\to TM$ such that $X_p\in T_pM$ doesn't neccesarily give a continuous map $X:S\to TM|_S$ and even worse things can happen when we consider smoothness. Something like this happens in the proof of Lemma 10.35 (Orthogonal Complement Bundles) where $M$ can be a immersed submanifold

So, in summary, how do we deal with immersed submanifolds? @[Jack Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1421/jack-lee)

Comment: Ugh -- you're right. My explanation of the immersed case was totally inadequate and very misleading. I've posted a correction on my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/) -- admittedly a little sketchy, but it at least points in the right direction. The answer by @Ken below gives a much more complete development of the essential ideas. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: But your attempted answer below doesn't work, unfortunately, because it need not be the case that $E|_S$ has the subspace topology.

Comment: @JackLee Thanks for answering Professor Lee. I still think $E|_S$ has the subspace topology. Could you check my expanded answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I am not 100% sure, but here's what I believe what the author really meant.)

**Short Answer**: If $\pi:E\to M$ is a (topological) vector bundle and $S\subseteq M$ is any subspace, then we denote by $E|_S\to S$ the restriction of $\pi:E\to M$ as you have defined. However, when $\pi:E\to M$ is a smooth vector bundle and $S\subseteq M$ is an immersed submanifold, we give $E|_S$ a smooth structure that makes it into an immersed (but possibly not embedded) submanifold of $E$. There is a good reason for this: Even though $E|_S$ may not be embedded in $E$, it has a nice property.

---

**An example of the case where $E|_S$ is not embedded**: Let $E=M=\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $\pi=\operatorname{Id}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$. Clearly $\pi:E\to M$ is a smooth vector bundle over $M$ (of rank $0$). Now let $S$ be the figure eight, which is an immersed submanifold in $M$. The chart lemma makes $\pi^{-1}(S)=E|_S$ into an immersed submanifold of $E$. Since $S$ has a self intersection, we cannot make $E|_S$ into a smooth manifold (nor even a topological manifold!) with respect to the subspace topology inherited from $E$. Thus we see that the chart lemma endowed $E|_S$ with a topology different from the subspace topology, i.e., $E|_S$ is not embedded.

---

**Long Answer**: Suppose $\pi :E\to M$ is a smooth vector bundle, and let $S$ be an immersed submanifold in $M$. The chart lemma (Lemma 10.6 in Lee's book) shows that $E|_S=\pi^{-1}(S)$ has a (unique) topology and a smooth structure with respect to which the restriction $\pi_S:E|_S\to S$ of $S$ is a smooth vector bundle with the following property:

- If $\Phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb{R}^k$ is a smooth local trivialization of $E$ over an open set $U\subseteq M$, then its restriction  $\Phi|_S:\pi^{-1}(U\cap S)\to(U\cap S)\times \mathbb{R}^k$ is a smooth local trivialization of $E|_S$.

It is easy to check that $E|_S$ is an immersed submanifold of $E$.It is also easy to check that in the case when $S$ has the subspace topology inherited from $M$ and is an immersed submanifold of $M$ (i.e., when $S$ is embedded), the topology of $E|_S$ given by the chart lemma agrees with the subspace topology inherited from $E$, so there is no conflict in what the symbol $E|_S$ means in this case. If $S$ is merely immersed, the chart lemma may endow $E|_S$ with a topology different from the subspace topology, so there is a little bit of ambiguity in what the symbol $E_S$ means. However, when $S$ is immersed but not embedded, we are keenly aware of the fact that it is is not "part of $M$", in the sense that it does not have the subspace topology. So there is little chance of confusion.

Although it may not be embedded in $E$, it resembles an embedded submanifold in the following sense:

> Let $X$ be a smooth manifold and let $f:X\to S$ and $F:X\to E$
> be smooth (resp. continuous) maps such that $\pi F=if$, where $i:S\to M$ denotes the inclusion. Then the map
> $F_{S}:X\to E\vert_{S}$ induced by $F$ is smooth (resp. continuous).

Before we get to the proof, let me note that this property explains justifies the arguments in Example 10.10 and lemma 10.35. Now we get back to the proof.

(Proof.) Let $x_{0}\in X$ and let $\Phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times\mathbb{R}^{k}$
be any smooth local trivialization of $E$ with $f(x_{0})\in U$.
By hypothesis, the map
$$
\Phi\circ F:(if)^{-1}(U)\to U\times\mathbb{R}^{k}
$$
is smooth. Since $\Phi$ commutes with the projection to $U$, we
can write $\Phi\circ F(x)=(if(x),\phi_{1}(x),\dots,\phi_{k}(x))$
for $x\in(if)^{-1}(U)$, and the functions $\phi_{1},\dots,\phi_{k}$
are smooth functions on $(if)^{-1}(U)$ (by the smoothness of $\Phi\circ F$).
Now the map $\Phi\vert_{S}\circ F_{S}:(if)^{-1}(U)\to(U\cap S)\times\mathbb{R}^{k}$
is given by $x\mapsto(f(x),\phi_{1}(x),\dots,\phi_{k}(x))$, so the
restriction of $F_{S}$ to $(if)^{-1}(U)$ is smooth. Thus $F_{S}$
is smooth on a neighbrohood of $x_{0}$. Since $x_{0}$ was arbitrary,
we are done.$\square$

Comment: I disagree with this sentence: "the chart lemma may endow $E|_S$ with a topology different from the subspace topology". 

If I recall correctly, I proved that the subspace topology and the topology given by the chart lemma are the same by noting that the identity map is a bijective local homeomorphism, thus an homeomorphism. Try to do that and tell me what you get. Also, I believe things break if $E|_S$ is merely an immersed submanifold. I'm mostly sure of this.

We really need Professor Lee here.

Comment: @Zero Consider the case where $E=M$ and $\pi=\operatorname{Id}_M$. In this case $\pi:E\to M$ is a smooth vector bundle over $M$ of rank 0, but the topology for $E|_S(=S)$ given by the chart lemma is nothing but the topology of $S$. The problem in your proof (I'll use the symbol from your answer) is that although $\pi|_S^{-1}(U\cap V)$ is open in $E|_S$ with the chart lemma topology and it has the same topology as the subspace topology inherited from $E$, it may not be open in $E|_S$ with the subspace topology.

Comment: @Zero (Recall that a map is a local homeomorphism if every point has a neighborhood that is mapped homeomorphically onto an *open* set of the codomain.

Comment: I believe that to prove that the identity is a local homeomorphism, I used the fact that $S$ has a topology such that the inclusion map is a topological immersion and that, locally, the identity is the composition of two homeomorphisms which are a trivialization and the inverse of another trivialization.

Comment: Are you sure that when you composed two trivializations (say $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$, ) the space $Y$ are given the same topology? $U\cap V$ is open in the immersed submanifold $S$, but it may not be open in the subspace $S\subseteq M$.

Comment: We are trying to prove that the spaces $Y$ have the same topology. The intersection is open in the subspace topology precisely because we consider a topological immersion.

Comment: The intersection may not be open in the subspace topology. See, for example, the discussion on the page 111, right after the proof of Proposition 5.22. (Since this site started asking me to avoid extended discussions, I think I will make this comment my final comment. Sorry.)

Comment: I will elaborate on this detail in two weeks, right now I have to study for my qualification exams. You may be right, but I remember considering the type of things you are questioning. I will comment on this answer when I edit my main answer. Also don't worry about that advertence.

Comment: I have added an example in which $E|_S$ may never be embedded in $E$. Thank you very much for taking time while preparing for the qual. It was my pleasure to have been able to have such a deep discussion here.  I wish you the best on your qual.

Comment: As I said, I was going to edit my answer after my qualification exams. I would like you to check it. Even Professor Lee responded in your favor, so I might lose this discussion :P

Comment: @Zero  Thank you very much for keeping your promise! It is nice to have a confirmation from the author himself. I greatly appreciate your dedication. I also thank Professor Lee for leaving us comments and MSE for making this discussion possible.

Comment: Why is $\Phi \circ \sigma:U\cap S \to U \times R^K$ smooth? $S$ is an immersed submanifold so $U \cap S$ may not be open in $S$.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Since $S$ is immersed in $M$, the inclusion $i:S\to M$ is continuous. Hence $i^{-1}(U)=U\cap S$ is open in $S$.

Comment: @Ken oh you're right thank you. But what does this justify from Example 10.10 and Lemma 10.35?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician Hm, you are right. Thank you for asking that. I should have stated a stronger property about $E\vert S$. I hope my edit clarifies your thoughts now. If you are interested, I recommend that you look up "universal property of pullbacks" and "pullback bundles."

Comment: @Ken Sorry but I can't really follow your new argument. $\pi: E \to M$, so $\pi \circ F : X \to M$, $f: X \to S$, and how is $\pi \circ F = f$? And $U$ is open in $M$, so why is $f^{-1}(U)$ open in $X$? Also why do we get $\Phi \circ F : f^{-1}(U) \to U \times R^k$? And why is $\Phi|_S \circ F|_S : f^{-1}(U \cap S) \to (U \cap S) \times R^k$? And why is this still smooth when $(U \cap S) \times R^k$ is not embedded in $U \times R^k$? For it to be smooth, it has to be continuous as a map into $(U \cap S) \times R^k$ but I don't see how we get this.

Comment: @Ken Besides $\Phi|_S:\pi^{-1}(U\cap S)\to (U\cap S)\times R^k$ as you wrote below the long answer is not a smooth local trivialization for $E|_S$ when $S$ is merely immersed. We need to find a locally embedded $V$ inside $U$ and restrict $\Phi$ to $\pi^{-1}(V)$, which becomes the smooth local trivialization. Check the list of corrections in Lee's book.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician I edited the answer. I hope everything is clear now. I think in your first comment, your confusion came from my notation: I used the same notation $f$ for both $f:X\to S$ and the composite $if:X\to M$, where $i:S\to M$ denotes the inclusion. This might feel a bit abusive, but it is very common; after all, the underlying set of $S$is a subset of that of $M$.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician As for your second comment, I do not think Lee says that $\Phi \vert_S$
is not a smooth local trivialization. He only says that the chart lemma applies to a restrictive class of local trivializations (although the restriction appears to be unecessary). Once you have verified that this gives us a smooth vector bundle $\pi_S: E\vert_S\to S$, then it is easy to check that every smooth section $\sigma:M\to E$ of 
$\pi$ restricts a smooth section of $\pi _S$. Combining this with Proposition 10.19, you can see that $\Phi\vert _S $ is a smooth local trivialization of $\pi _S$.

Answer (score 2):

**2nd Edit 20/06/2019** THIS ANSWER HAS A MISTAKE IN **EXAMPLE 10.8*** (AND THEREFORE IN THE REST BECAUSE IT DEPENDS ON IT), $\pi|_S:E|_S\to S$ NEED NOT BE CONTINUOUS WHEN $S$ IS MERELY IMMERSED AND $E|_S$ HAS THE SUBSPACE TOPOLOGY.

**Edit 20/06/2019**: Both @[Jack Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1421/jack-lee) and @[Ken](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/544921/ken) think $E|_S$ might not have have the subspace topology. I still think it has, so I'm gonna write the details about this in **Example 10.8***. If there are any mistakes, I would like you guys to point them out in the comments.

I think I arrived at a satisfactory answer. Lee is essentially right, immersed manifolds can be considered, but I'd like to explain it a little bit more.

**Example 10.8*** (**Restriction of a vector bundle**). Suppose $\pi:E\to M$ is a rank-$k$ vector bundle and $S\subseteq M$ is a subset with a topology such that the inclusion map $S\hookrightarrow M$ is a topological immersion (defined after Theorem 4.25). We define ***the restriction of $E$ to $S$*** to be the set $E|_S=\bigcup_{p\in S}E_p$ with the subspace topology and the projection $\pi|_S:E|_S\to S$ is obtained by restricting $\pi$. Let $p\in S$. If $\Phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb{R}^k$ is a local trivialization of $E$ over $U\subseteq M$ with $p\in U$ and $V$ a neighborhood of $p$ in $S$ such that $V\hookrightarrow M$ is a topological embedding, by restricting $\Phi$ we can obtain a bijective map  $\Phi|_S:(\pi|_S)^{-1}(U\cap V)\to (U\cap V)\times \mathbb{R}^k$, and since the topology on $U\cap V$ is given by the subspace topology of $S$ and the subspace topology of $M$ are the same (because $V\hookrightarrow M$ is a topological embedding) and $E|_S$ is a subspace of $E$, we can check that these form local trivializations for a vector bundle structure on $E|_S$.

If $E$ is a smooth vector bundle and $S\subseteq M$ is an immersed or embedded submanifold, it follows easily from the chart lemma than $E|_S$ is a smooth vector bundle. We now verify that the topology on $E|_S$ given by the chart lemma is the subspace topology. We do this by proving that the identity map $id:E|_S\to E|_S$, where the domain has the subspace topology and the codomain has the topology given by the chart lemma, is a bijective local homeomorphism, and thus a homeomorphism. It is obvious that $id$ is bijective. Let $v\in E_p$ where $p\in S$. Pick $U$ and $V$ as in the previous paragraph, such that $p \in U\cap V$. In both cases, $\Phi|_S:(\pi|_S)^{-1}(U\cap V)\to (U\cap V)\times \mathbb{R}^k$ is a homeomorphism, thus $id|(\pi|_S)^{-1}(U\cap V)=(\Phi|_S)^{-1}\circ \Phi|_S$ is a homeomorphism and then $id$ is a local homeomorphism. In particular, if $S\subseteq M$ is a smooth (embedded or immersed) submanifold, then the restricted bundle $TM|_S$ is called the ***ambient tangent bundle over*** $M$.

**Example 10.28(b)***. If $E\to M$ is a smoooth vector bundle and $S\subseteq M$ is an immersed submanifold with or without boundary, then it is easy to prove that the inclusion map $E|_S\hookrightarrow E$ is an smooth immersion, and since $E|_S$ has the subspace topology, it is actually an smooth embedding and $E|_S$ is an embedded submanifold of $E$. Thus the inclusion map $E|_S\hookrightarrow E$ is a smooth bundle homomorphism covering the inclusion of $S$ into $M$.

**Example 10.10(b)***. Given an immersed submanifold $S\subseteq M$ with or without boundary, a (smooth) section of the ambient tangent bundle $TM|_S\to S$ is called a (smooth) vector field along $S$. Because $TM|_S$ is an embedded submanifold of $TM$, it is a continuous (respectively smooth) map $X:S\to TM$ such that $X_p\in T_pM$ for each $p\in S$.

As an application of all of this. I would like to prove the following theorem

**Theorem.** If $S\subseteq M$ is an immersed submanifold, then $di:TS\to TM$ is an embedding where $i:S\hookrightarrow M$ is the inclusion map.

**Proof.** From the coordinate representation of $di$ given in the proof of Proposition 3.21, we see that $di$ is an immersion. Set $n=\dim M$ and $k=\dim S$. Let $p\in S$ and set $D_q=di_q(T_qS)$ for $q\in S$. Since $i$ is a local embedding, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $S$ such that the inclusion map $V\hookrightarrow M$ is a smooth embedding. Let $(U,(x^i))$ be a slice chart for $V$ with $p\in U$. Then $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}:U\cap V\to TM|_S\right)_{i=1,\dots,k}$ are smooth local sections with the property that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}|_q,\dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}|_q$ for a basis of $D_q$ for each $q\in U\cap V$. Thus by Theorem 10.32, $di(TS)=\bigcup_{p\in S}di_p(T_pS)$ is a smooth subbundle of $TM|_S$. Since $di(TS)$ is an embedded submanifold of $TM|_S$, we can consider the smooth map $di:TS\to di(TS)$ which is also bijective and an immersion. Thus by the Global Rank Theorem, $di:TS\to di(TS)$ is a diffeomorphism and hence $di:TS\to TM$ is an embedding.

Comment: Here's your mistake in showing that $E|_S$ has the subspace topology when $S$ is an immersed submanifold: It's true that you can find a subset $W\subset E|_S$ (namely $W = (\pi|_S)^{-1}(U\cap V)$ in your notation) such that the identity restricts to a homeomorphism from $W$ in one topology to $W$ in the other topology. But the problem is that $W$ need not be open in the subspace topology, so it does not follow that $\operatorname{id}$ is a local homeomorphism. To see what can go wrong, consider the trivial $\mathbb R^1$-bundle over the figure-$8$ submanifold of Example 5.19.

Comment: @JackLee I think $W\subseteq E|_S$ is open in the subspace topology because $\pi|_S:E|_S\to S$ is continuous when $E|_S$ is given the subspace topology and $U\cap V\subseteq S$ is open in $S$ because $U\cap V=i^{-1}(U)$ is open in $V$ where $i:V\to M$ is the inclusion map, which is continuous, and $V$ is open in $S$, so $U\cap V$ is open in $S$. Thus $W=(\pi|_S)^{-1}(U\cap V)$ is open in the subspace topology.

Comment: Assuming that $S$ is an immersed but not embedded submanifold, $\pi|_S\colon E|_S\to S$ need not be continuous when $E|_S$ is given the subspace topology and $S$ has the given topology as an immersed submanifold. Again, I point you to the example of a trivial bundle over the figure-8 space.

Comment: @JackLee You are totally right, Professor Lee, I screwed up big time there. Thanks again for taking time to clarify your wonderful book.